# Where Do I Get A WETH Flashloan On Goerli Ethereum?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, javascript, addresses, flash-loans

I'm trying to test a flashloan on goerli ethereum.  It seems AAVE may no longer be supporting this for WETH flashloans (if they ever did).  Anybody know how I can run test Flashloans on Goerli Ethereum?

Alternatively - what's the proper address on Sepolia that actually has WETH and I can run flashloans against?

Comment: Because it's testnet, you can always deploy your own loan reserves and trading pools to simulate flashloans.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that can help you is the official document, see it from this link: https://docs.aave.com/developers/guides/flash-loans And also to test all the test nets that are supported, there are at this address: https://docs.aave.com/developers/deployed-contracts/v3-testnet-addresses